# Не получается вывести пользовательское поле раздела в Битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Нужно вывести пользовательское поле UF_TOP_BLOCK над карточками только на странице "Климатическое оборудование" (она является подразделом инфоблока "Продукты")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так задается текст в поле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так я его вывожу в шаблоне подразделов (айди нужного подраздела 104):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что теперь это поле выводится на всех подразделах, а не только на подразделе "Климатическое оборудование". Хочется выводить просто проверкой на пустоту, то есть, если поле пустое, то ничего не выводим, а если нет, то выводим значение поля нужного подраздела. Не знаю, как это реализовать?

Comment: [`empty`](https://www.php.net/empty) уже изобретен.

Answer (score 0):

Если шаблон для компонента catalog.section, то используйте в фильтре значения из параметров компонента:

```
$arFilter = Array('IBLOCK_ID' => $arParams['IBLOCK_ID'], 'ID' => $arParams['SECTION_ID'], 'GLOBAL_ACTIVE' => 'Y);
```